Custom component with react hook form and material UI not displaying in UI
I am using the Radio Button from UI with react hook form. The buttons are situated in Material UI DataGrid. I want based on the selection of the radio button to restrict other fields from the table. But for some reason my field with the radio buttons does not show in the UI. The only times it shows is when you double click the field to select a value.
Here is my custom componenet:
export type Props<T> = {
  name: keyof T;
  gridWidth?: string;
  control: Control<T>;
};

export default function GridRadioInput<T extends FieldValues>({
  name,
  gridWidth = '100%',
  control,
}: Props<T>) {
  const options = [
    { id: false, name: 'Fixed Date' },
    { id: true, name: 'By Appointment' },
  ];

  return (
    <Grid item width={gridWidth}>
      <Controller
        name={name as Path<T>}
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <RadioGroup
            value={value !== undefined ? value.toString() : 'true'}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
            row
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={option.id.toString()}
                value={option.id.toString()}
                control={<Radio />}
                label={option.name}
              />
            ))}
          </RadioGroup>
        )}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
}

Here is where I create the columns for my table:
const GridTextField = ({ field, id }) => {
  const { control, trigger } = useFormContext();
  const name = `${id}.${field}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    trigger();
  }, []);

  return <GridFormInputText name={name} key={name} control={control} />;
};

const renderTextfieldCell = (params) => {
  const { field, id } = params;

  return <GridTextField field={field} id={id} />;
};

const GridRadioField = ({ field, id }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  const name = `${id}.${field}`;

  return <GridRadioInput name={name} key={name} control={control} />;
};

const renderRadioFieldCell = (params) => {
  const { field, id } = params;
  return <GridRadioField field={field} id={id} />;
};

export const useColumnsPanel = ({
  rowsStatus,
  rowModesModel,
  onSave,
  onCancel,
  onEdit,
  onDelete,
}): GridColDef[] => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'number',
      headerName: t('number'),
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 120,
      editable: true,
      hideable: false,
      renderEditCell: renderTextfieldCell,
      renderCell: renderDataGridCellExpand,
    },
    {
      field: 'title',
      headerName: t('title'),
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 120,
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: renderTextfieldCell,
      renderCell: renderDataGridCellExpand,
    },
    {
      field: 'appointmentType',
      headerName: t('appointmentType'),
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 120,
      editable: true,
      type: 'boolean',
      renderEditCell: renderRadioFieldCell,
      renderCell: renderDataGridCellExpand,
    },
    {
      field: 'acceptanceDate',
      headerName: t('acceptanceDate'),
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 120,
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: renderTextfieldCell,
      renderCell: renderDataGridCellExpand,
    },
    {
      field: 'period',
      headerName: t('period'),
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 120,
      editable: true,
      renderEditCell: renderTextfieldCell,
      renderCell: renderDataGridCellExpand,
    },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      headerName: t('actions'),
      width: 100,
      getActions: (props) => {
        const { id, row } = props;
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;
        return getDatagridActions({
          row,
          rowStatus: rowsStatus[id],
          isInEditMode,
          onSave,
          onCancel,
          onEdit,
          onDelete,
        });
      },
    },
  ];

  return columns;
};

and here my main component where I am using the columns:
const ACCEPTANCEMILESTONE_ROW_ID: number = 0;
interface AcceptanceMilestone {
  id?: number;
  number: number;
  title: string;
  acceptanceDate: string;
  appointmentType?: boolean;
}

const ACCEPTANCEMILESTONE_ROW: AcceptanceMilestone = Object.freeze({
  id: ACCEPTANCEMILESTONE_ROW_ID,
  number: 1,
  longName: '',
  title: '',
  acceptanceDate: '',
  appointmentType: true,
});

const DetailPanelContent = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const rowsStatus = {};
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = useState<GridRowModesModel>({});
  const [rows, setRows] = useState<AcceptanceMilestone[]>([
    ACCEPTANCEMILESTONE_ROW,
  ]);

  // Use useColumns hook with simulated arguments
  const handleSave = (rowIndex: number) => {
    if (rowModesModel[rowIndex]) {
      // Check if rowModesModel contains the rowIndex
      setRowModesModel((prevModes) => ({
        ...prevModes,
        [rowIndex]: { mode: GridRowModes.View }, // Switch mode to view after saving
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    // Implement the logic for canceling the changes.
  };

  function handleEdit(row: AcceptanceMilestone) {
    const { id, ...rowData } = row;
    if (id !== undefined) {
      setRows((prevRows) =>
        prevRows.map((prevRow) =>
          prevRow.id === id ? { ...prevRow, ...rowData } : prevRow
        )
      );
      setRowModesModel((prevModes) => ({
        ...prevModes,
        [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit },
      }));
    }
  }

  const handleDelete = () => {
    // Implement the logic for deleting a row.
  };

  const columns = useColumnsPanel({
    rowsStatus,
    rowModesModel,
    onSave: handleSave,
    onCancel: handleCancel,
    onEdit: handleEdit,
    onDelete: handleDelete,
  });

  const addEmptyRow = () => {
    setRows((currentRows) => [
      ...currentRows,
      {
        id: currentRows.length + 1, // Assign a new id
        number: currentRows.length + 1,
        title: '',
        acceptanceDate: '',
        appointmentType: true,
      },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container sx={classes.topContainer}>
      <h3>Acceptance Milestone</h3>
      <Grid item sx={classes.button}>
        <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={addEmptyRow}>
          {t('create')}
        </Button>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item sx={classes.dataGrid}>
        <DataGridPro rows={rows} columns={columns} getRowId={(row) => row.id} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default DetailPanelContent;

